# Is it possible to use phpspec with functional programming?

Tags: drupal, bdd, phpspec

Is it possible to use phpspec in functional programming? I would like to use it in Drupal project but can't find any useful example. As far as I see phpspec can be used only with OO programming. Is it true? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need. I was thinking about cloning the ObjectBehaviour to A FunctionBehaviour class that Can be used for this.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer... I know you can't comment right now, but think about up voting if you have the same problem =]